# Read part of a text-based file

Tags: matlab, readfile

I had a text-based file with .ptx suffix. It contains the point cloud information please see the following example

```
100
50
0.352 -5.207 -0.823 0.238 61 61 61
0.345 -5.202 -0.824 0.234 60 60 60
...
```

**Question:**

How can I load the file from the third row (ignore the first two rows) and save is as a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html).

Something like:

```
in = textscan('sample.ptx','%f %f %f %f %f %f %f','HeaderLines',2)
```

You can specify a number of header lines to skip using `'HeaderLines'`. The `%f` refers to the format of the input data. Hope that helps.

Comment: Good answer. `'HeaderLines'` is a good solution. I took the liberty of formatting your answer -- hope you don't mind.  Also, I would suggest using `'%f %f %f %f %d %d %d'` as the format specifier since the last three columns seem to be integers rather than floating point.

Comment: @chappjc Thanks for the help. Could you please help me out a bit further. How should I save/transform the file in to matrix after I 'textscan' it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example of how to apply textscan and transform the result in to a matrix:

```
fid = fopen('textscantest.txt','r');
assert(fid~=1); % verify file is opened
C = textscan(fid,'%f %f %f %f %f %f %f','HeaderLines',2);
fclose(fid);
M = [C{:}]
```

Note that since you want it all in the same matrix, you need the same data type and all `%f` is required for each column.